# Visual Studio 2017 - A working project no longer compiles

Tags: .net, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I had to reinstall my machine. So After installing Windows I decided to install VS2017 (was working with VS2015) on a project. VS2017 converted the project files to 2017 but now the project doesn't compile. It has 832 errors. This is a project that was compiling without a problem before I reinstalled my machine.

The error that keeps repeating itself is:

> Unable to satisfy conflicting requests for 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms': Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms (>= 1.0.2) (via package/Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.1), Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms (>= 1.1.0) (via package/NETStandard.Library 1.6.1), Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms (>= 1.0.1) (via package/Libuv 1.9.1), Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms (>= 1.1.0) (via package/NETStandard.Library 1.6.1), Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms (>= 1.1.0) (via package/NETStandard.Library 1.6.1), Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms (>= 1.1.0) (via package/System.Security.Principal.Windows 4.3.0), Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms (>= 1.1.0) (via package/NETStandard.Library 1.6.1), Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms (>= 1.1.0) (via package/System.Diagnostics.Process 4.3.0), Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms (>= 1.1.0) (via package/NETStandard.Library 1.6.1), Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms (>= 1.1.0) (via package/NETStandard.Library 1.6.1), Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms (>= 1.1.0) (via package/System.Diagnostics.Process 4.3.0), Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms (>= 1.1.0) (via package/NETStandard.Library 1.6.1)

I see that I have some NuGet updates to some projects in the solution but some of them are not updating without any specific error.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are targeting .net core 1.1 (assumption taken from the entries in the error message), try removing all ocurrances of `<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>` and `<NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>` in the csproj files and update all other nuget packages. Also remove all `<PackageReference>` elements that contain `Microsoft.NETCore.App` or `NETStandard.Library` if there are any.

Comment: Should I target something other than .net core 1.1? is .net core 2.0 already GA?

Comment: no it isn't, but it looks like you have a conflict with the same package referenced by different versions of the packages that make up ".net core" and ".net standard", which are no longer explicitly referenced, but the migration will override the version if the project.json explicitly contains the versions. If you still have more problems, we will need to see the involved csproj files..

Comment: A strange thing... all my project.json files are gone from all projects... Where did all those settings go?

Comment: There is no more project.json, all in the csproj file now. (project.json and the .net core tooling in VS 2015 is no longer supported)

Comment: I did as you said. Removed all that needs to be removed. Unfortunately, it still fails on the same errors. And I can't upgrade NuGet packages due to this error.